# How to add condition in Android View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `Arraylist` that contain a `hashmap`. hashmap contain a Topic name, Name and value. For example `hashmap` object like this.(I did not add the key for the example.)

```
{"Topic A", "Name 1" , "100"}  
{"Topic A", "Name 2" , "100"}  
{"Topic A", "Name 3" , "100"}  
{"Topic A", "Name 4" , "100"}  
{"Topic B", "Name 1" , "100"}  
{"Topic B", "Name 2" , "100"}  
{"Topic B", "Name 3" , "100"}  
{"Topic B", "Name 4" , "100"}  
{"Topic C", "Name 1" , "100"}  
{"Topic C", "Name 2" , "100"}  
{"Topic C", "Name 3" , "100"}  
{"Topic C", "Name 4" , "100"}  
{"Topic D", "Name 1" , "100"}  
{"Topic D", "Name 2" , "100"}
```

I want to make a list view like this

```
Topic A
=========================
name 1                100
name 2                100
name 3                100
name 4                100

Topic B
==========================
name 1                100
name 2                100
name 3                100
name 4                100


Topic C
==========================
name 1                100
name 2                100
name 3                100
name 4                100

Topic D
==========================
name 1                100
name 2                100
name 3                100
name 4                100
```

Here is my `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method................

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null)
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_card_type, null);

    mTopic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.topic);
    mItemname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_of_item);
    mValue = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.value_of_item); 

    mTopic.setText(myArrayList.get(position).get("Topic"));

    mItemname.setText(myArrayList.get(position).get(
            "Name"));
    mValue.setText(myArrayList.get(position).get("Value"));
    return v;

}
```

Here is my list view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="28dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_of_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="28dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value_of_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="28dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I try to do that with add a condition inside of the `getView` method using `position` value. But it confused me. 
Can please someone suggest me what to do..............

Comment: add some code of array list..

Comment: Without key how are you able to check this `myArrayList.get(position).get("Topic")?` Where did you set `Topic` as a key into hashmap ?

Comment: create your item file with Topic and 1 row for name and value and just check if Topic value is same then set visibility of topic gone else visible

Comment: items in listview are recycled every time the view changes. You need to hold view objects in ViewHolder. For example: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: that 'myArrayList' has values. I checked with debug option. It is ok.
I want to know how to add such a condition in 'getView' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some thing like this, You can make changes, i am just adding a sample

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null)
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_card_type, null);

    mTopic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.topic);
    mItemname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_of_item);
    mValue = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.value_of_item); 

      String topic = "";

if(!(myArrayList.get(position).get("Topic").equals(topic )))
{
     mTopic.setText(myArrayList.get(position).get("Topic"));
      topic = myArrayList.get(position).get("Topic");
}else{
mTopic.setText("");}


    mItemname.setText(myArrayList.get(position).get(
            "Name"));
    mValue.setText(myArrayList.get(position).get("Value"));
    return v;

}
```

Comment: I try in your method. But it do not work. I feel that your method must work. I can't find what went wrong..

Comment: What you are getting?? i have updated answer try that too and you will not get the exact as in question, you need to do some thing more

Comment: finally I have made it. Still it has some issues. But I think I can manage that.
Thank you @Sree

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
// define this as global
String lastTopic = "";

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null)
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    TextValue tv_topic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_topic);
    TextValue tv_item_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
    TextValue tv_item_value = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_value);

    if (!(myArrayList.get(position).get("Topic").equals(lastTopic))) {

        tvTopic.setText(myArrayList.get(position).get("Topic"));
        lastTopic = myArrayList.get(position).get("Topic");

    } else {

        tvTopic.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    tv_item_name.setText(myArrayList.get(position).get("Name"));
    tv_item_value.setText(myArrayList.get(position).get("Value"));

    return v;

}
```